# Character limit of property value in Google Apps Script API

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I am testing G Suite Add On and for this purpose, I need to know maximum character limit of Property value.

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) here says, quota limit for property value size is 9 KB. As the size of char vary in different language, what value of char size shall I take to calculate character limit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can estimate that 1 KB is around 1024 characters.
- This means that 9 KB corrsponds to around 9216 characters.